# Python regex match numbers or nothing

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match

I have strings:

1st one

```
\-1,1\N,0.0464128206,0.1106913625,-0.0261445305\
```

2nd one

```
\-1,1\N,0.,0.,0.\
```

It can be done manually to the

```
 \-1,1\N,0.0,0.0,0.0\
```

but I am trying to make script working without any editing

My RegEx is

```
\d,\d\\[A-Z],[-]?\d+.\d+,[-]?\d+.\d+,[-]?\d+.\d+
```

How to make RegEx work on \d+ or just skip it if is not present?

UPD:
I want to make RegEx which will get true for both strings. How to make this part '\d+.\d+' to skip second \d+ if it is absent?
[\d+]? is not working.

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to get. If we're given string 1, what do you expect as output? Same for string 2.

Comment: @Jivan please, have a look at the update

Comment: @FreddieV4 I want to make Regex which will find both string equal to the conditions 'numbers point [numpers or just nothing] comma' - I don't understand how to make this regex...

Comment: That sounds like you want `\d*` (which is equivalent to `(\d+)?`).

Comment: @XuMuK okay, it's clearer with the edit indeed

Comment: @melpomene yes, `\d*` is the regex I have been looking for. But also there was a little mistake - I used `.`, not `\.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the part after the `.` from `\d+` to `\d*`, like this:

```
\d,\d\\[A-Z],[-]?\d+\.\d*,[-]?\d+\.\d*,[-]?\d+\.\d*
```

The interpretation of `\d+\.\d*` being:

**at least one digit then exactly one dot then zero or one or several digits**

Note that I also changed your `.` to `\.` (`.` meaning any character).

Link to debuggex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/nSKH3lbNr8opO09o

-- ***Update***

Your regex could be simplified a bit to this:

```
\d,\d\\[A-Z](?:,-?\d+\.\d*){3}
```

It simply factorizes your `,\d+\.\d*` knowing that this group is repeated three times. It also changes `[-]` to `-` which is cleaner.

The `(?: ... ){3}` syntax meaning a non-capturing group repeated three times.

Link to the updated debuggex: https://www.debuggex.com/r/Cni47UR71BCgpa2A

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I have been trying to get! And thank you for the debugger link! Ok, I will remember, that just point is as any single character.

Comment: @XuMuK thanks - I updated the regex a bit to make it simpler and cleaner